# Using purrr to efficiently count regex matches in a large dataframe

Tags: r, regex, tidyverse, purrr

**Edited to change the regex and show my `tidyr/dplyr` solution**

I am looking for an efficient way (preferably `purrr`) way to handle a lot searching and counting regex patterns in a large dataframe.

Here is a simple example of what I'm trying to achieve.

Say I have a data frame of sentences:

```
  library(stringr)  
dat <- tibble(id = 1:5,
                  text = sentences[1:5])
dat

# A tibble: 5 x 2
     id text                                       
  <int> <chr>                                      
1     1 The birch canoe slid on the smooth planks. 
2     2 Glue the sheet to the dark blue background.
3     3 It's easy to tell the depth of a well.     
4     4 These days a chicken leg is a rare dish.   
5     5 Rice is often served in round bowls.
```

I also have a table of search patterns classified by type and corresponding regexes:

```
searches <- tibble(type = c("Article","Article","Preposition","Preposition","Preposition","Preposition"),
                   pattern = c("the","a","on","of","in","to"),
                   regex = c("\\b[Tt]he\\b", "\\b[Aa]\\b","\\b[Oo]n\\b","\\b[Oo]f\\b",
                             "\\b[Ii]n\\b","\\b[Tt]o\\b"))

searches

  # A tibble: 6 x 3
  type        pattern regex         
  <chr>       <chr>   <chr>         
1 Article     the     "\\b[Tt]he\\b"
2 Article     a       "\\b[Aa]\\b"  
3 Preposition on      "\\b[Oo]n\\b" 
4 Preposition of      "\\b[Oo]f\\b" 
5 Preposition in      "\\b[Ii]n\\b" 
6 Preposition to      "\\b[Tt]o\\b"
```

I'd like to iterate through each search pattern for each sentence, and count the number of patterns found, so that the output looks something like:

```
   # A tibble: 9 x 5
     id sentence                                    type        pattern count
  <int> <chr>                                       <chr>       <chr>   <int>
1     1 The birch canoe slid on the smooth planks.  article     the         2
2     1 The birch canoe slid on the smooth planks.  preposition on          1
3     2 Glue the sheet to the dark blue background. article     the         2
4     2 Glue the sheet to the dark blue background. preposition to          1
5     3 It's easy to tell the depth of a well.      article     a           1
6     3 It's easy to tell the depth of a well.      preposition of          1
7     3 It's easy to tell the depth of a well.      preposition to          1
8     4 These days a chicken leg is a rare dish.    article     a           2
9     5 Rice is often served in round bowls.        preposition in          1
```

The real data and search table are several orders of magnitude bigger, so I want to avoid using a loop. I know there must be a way of doing it with a couple of `map` calls or `pmap`, but I'm having trouble getting my head around it.

**Added solution with `tidyr`**

This seems to work, but I wonder if a purrr alternative would be quicker:

```
crossing(text = dat$text,regex =searches$regex)%>% 
mutate(count = str_count(text,regex)) %>% 
inner_join(searches,.) %>% 
inner_join(dat,.) %>% 
filter(count>0) %>% 
select(-regex)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `map_df` -

```
library(tidyverse)

map_df(searches$regex, ~dat %>%
                      mutate(count = str_count(text, .x)) %>%
                      filter(count > 0)) %>%
  arrange(id)

#     id text                                        count
#   <int> <chr>                                       <int>
# 1     1 The birch canoe slid on the smooth planks.      2
# 2     1 The birch canoe slid on the smooth planks.      1
# 3     2 Glue the sheet to the dark blue background.     2
# 4     2 Glue the sheet to the dark blue background.     1
# 5     3 It's easy to tell the depth of a well.          1
# 6     3 It's easy to tell the depth of a well.          1
# 7     3 It's easy to tell the depth of a well.          1
# 8     3 It's easy to tell the depth of a well.          1
# 9     4 These days a chicken leg is a rare dish.        2
#10     5 Rice is often served in round bowls.            1
```

Of if you need all the information from `searches` dataframe use `pmap_df` -

```
pmap_df(searches, ~dat %>%
                  mutate(type = ..1, 
                         pattern = ..2, 
                         count = str_count(text, ..3)) %>% 
       filter(count > 0)) %>%
  arrange(id)

#      id text                                        type        pattern count
#   <int> <chr>                                       <chr>       <chr>   <int>
# 1     1 The birch canoe slid on the smooth planks.  Article     the         2
# 2     1 The birch canoe slid on the smooth planks.  Preposition on          1
# 3     2 Glue the sheet to the dark blue background. Article     the         2
# 4     2 Glue the sheet to the dark blue background. Preposition to          1
# 5     3 It's easy to tell the depth of a well.      Article     the         1
# 6     3 It's easy to tell the depth of a well.      Article     a           1
# 7     3 It's easy to tell the depth of a well.      Preposition of          1
# 8     3 It's easy to tell the depth of a well.      Preposition to          1
# 9     4 These days a chicken leg is a rare dish.    Article     a           2
#10     5 Rice is often served in round bowls.        Preposition in          1
```

Comment: The pmap version is exactly what I wanted, thanks!